# Properly hide UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` that I want to appear only in certain instances of a `UITableViewCell`. Depending on what information a user inputs, that button will be available to them. However, when I delete a cell that has the visible button, the default cell displaying instructions still holds an unwanted visible button.

Here is my code for `CellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"a" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *subtractPill = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [subtractPill setTitle:@"I took a pill." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:subtractPill];
    [subtractPill addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(subtractPill:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (self.delegate.medicineList.count==0){
        subtractPill.hidden=YES; //This code does not hide button.
        self.defaultText = @"Tap \"+\" button to add medicine.";
        cell.textLabel.text = self.defaultText;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @" ";
        return cell;
    }
    else{
        subtractPill.frame = CGRectMake(175.0f, 5.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f);
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i pills remaining.", temp.CurrentNumOfPieces];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here is my code for the Subtract Pill button:

```
- (void)subtractPill:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =
    [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    Medicine *x = [self.delegate.medicineList objectAtIndex:row];
    [x decreaseBy:1];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is my code for editing and deleting cells in the tableview.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    if (self.delegate.medicineList.count==0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [self.delegate.medicineList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

As of now, the default cell displaying the words "Tap the + button to add medicine." is overlapping the SubtractPill button when that cell is deleted. In other words, when the cell containing the button is deleted, the button is not made invisible.
I also tried changing the button's frame to make it invisible on the screen, but this did not work either. I came here after researching similar problems and have come to the conclusion that the hidden property of a button has a glitch or a characteristic that I am not yet aware of. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I answered my own question: I was simply putting the hidden property in the wrong place. I still do not fully understand why it was not working, but when I placed the hidden property in the editing and deleting methods for the tableview, the button no longer appeared.